# Fetch customer profile in a component rule

Tags: 7, views, commerce, rules, i18n-l10n

I'm working on a multi-lingual webshop and I'm trying to create a system for commerce where an admin can accept or reject orders. I've done this by creating a view that lists all pending orders and then I'm using bulk operations with 'accept' and 'reject' buttons to send a list of selected orders too a component rule that changes the order status. This works fine, except that I also want to send an e-mail to the person who made the order when the order is rejected. Again, sending the e-mail is not a problem, since it is stored within the order, what I'm having trouble with is sending the e-mail in the customer's language.

The site allows for anonymous orders, so referring too the order's owner for the language is not an option. I can't store extra information in an order either, so I added a hidden field too the customer profile that stores the language. However, all I have to work with is the list of orders. When I try to fetch the customer profile I don't get access too the field values, only the profile's ID and User ID.

Is there any way to fetch the complete profile, or possibly even better, is there a way to send the language string as parameter too the component rule with from the view?

Comment: How do you plan to populate this hidden field in the user profile that is completed by Commerce upon Anon order? Why can you not add extra fields to the order?

Answer (score 0):

Which module you using for customer profile. Are you using user profile like profile_load_profile($account);

Comment: No, the customer profile from commerce.